# How to create new key-bindings for ecplipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-10, editor, key-bindings

Most germans probably know the hassle to reach specific symbols like "{" or "}" within the german keyboard layout, that are often used, when programming in java.

Does anyone know a simple way to rebind those keys for the java editor in eclipse? I'd love to have it the following way, but I am open to alternatives too, as long as they are easy to reach:

```
ALT GR + Ö results in "{"
ALT GR + Ä results in "}"
```

I tried several third party keybinding tools like Sharpkeys, but most of them don't recognize those specific german keys within their layouts. I also tried inner eclipse solutions like templates, but those don't feel naturally to use, since you can't bind them to a key. I also tried macro add ons, but those usually can only hold the last recorded macro.

Anyone with a nice clean idea on how to solve this?

OS = Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following to type <kbd>ö</kbd>/<kbd>ä</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> for `{`/`}`:

1. In ***Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Templates***:

   1. Click ***New...***
   2. Enter/choose the following values:
      *Name:* **`ö`**
      *Context:* ***Java***
      *Description:* **`{`**
      *Pattern:* **`{`**
   3. Repeat the last two steps for **`ä`** and **`}`**
2. In ***Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Content Assist*** add `öä` as ***Auto activations triggers for Java*** (by default it is `.`, so change it to `.öä`)

Result: In the Java editor, if you type <kbd>ö</kbd>/<kbd>ä</kbd>, the content assist automatically opens and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will select the ö/ä template.